# UI Router event on navigate to self page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router for my page routing in my AngularJS app. I'm encountering an issue where if I click a hyperlink on a page that refers to the page/route I'm already on (i.e. self), nothing will happen.

For example, if you're scrolled halfway down a page and you click a hyperlink that refers to the current page, it will seem as though the link doesn't load, when in actual fact nothing needs to be loaded as the user is already on the right page.

The goal in this situation is to have the viewport moved to the top of the page, but I cannot get any event from ui-router for this event. I've tried $stateChangeStart and $stateChangeSuccess, but as no route change occurs, these do not fire.

My urls are of the form http://localhost:3000/projects/myproject and ui-router is configured as follows:

```
state('app.projects', {
    url: '/projects/:projectname',
    templateUrl: 'projects.html',
    controller: 'ProjectsCtrl'
}).
```

Without adding extra logic in the controller (which would obfuscate the natural href="projects/myproject" format), what can be done to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Without controller:

```
<a ui-sref="stateName({reload: true})" target="_blank">Link Text</a>
```

With controller:

```
$state.go($state.name, {}, {reload: true});
```

Comment: As per the question, I don't want to perform this logic in the controller as it means the url target can't be opened in a new tab in the right click menu, for SEO the links become unclear, and there is no clean way to identify the links when they are inserted into the page from another service.

Comment: sorry about that - updated my response but the concept is still the same.

Comment: yes, same concept. ideally i would be able to intercept a 'stateChangeRequest' event which would fire before stateChangeStart and cause a reload there if the current and target were the same. unfortunately i can't accept your answer on this one as it doesn't meet the question criteria of not obfuscating the natural href format. thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `#` at the end of the link. `href="projects/myproject#"`

Comment: using what you've provided doesn't make the page jump to the head like normal. i'm not sure why this is.